# Reading from Hive through Apache Beam

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

Can you please suggest how to read from Hive through Apache beam and save it in Row format PCollection?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HCatalogIO` I/O to read and write data from Hive. More details can be found [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/hcatalog/#reading-using-hcatalogio)

Comment: It's true that you can use HCatalogIO to read Hive, but be aware that conversion to Rows is not yet supported according to this recent email: https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/r6cc3558adf4652ab6dd2f54ad89413de13d0d43eec02e587ebfeb0f4%40%3Cuser.beam.apache.org%3E